# How to calculate combination and permutation in R?

Tags: r, combinations

How one can calculate the number of combinations and permutations in R?

The [Combinations package](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Combinations/html/00Index.html) failed to install on Linux with the following message:

```
> install.packages("Combinations")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/maxim/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘Combinations’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

Comment: Why was this closed? It is not asking for a recommendation about a book or software library, but about calculation of combinatoric function in a specific language. Equivalent question for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838368/calculating-the-amount-of-combinations) and other languages are not closed...

Comment: I edited the question to remove the mention of software recommendation. Given the quality answers (and useful discussions in comments) I believe this question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `combinat` package with R 2.13:

```
install.packages("combinat")
require(combinat)
permn(3)
combn(3, 2)
```

If you want to know the number of combination/permutations, then check the size of the result, e.g.:

```
length(permn(3))
dim(combn(3,2))[2]
```

Comment: Is there something that could just give me a number of possible combinations, rather then printing them all?

Comment: @MaximVeksler Take a look at `choose`. (`choose(5, 2) == ncol(combn(5, 2))`)

Comment: This site can be used as alternate:      http://www.englishact.com/Permutation/index.php

Comment: Does not work with k = 0  or k = n. 5C0 or 5C5 should return 1 but it returns null.

Answer (score 57):

The function [combn](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) is in the standard utils package (i.e. already installed)

[choose](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html) is also already available in the Special {base}

Comment: wow alot of hassle for a simple question that its answer was 3 words "the choose function"

Comment: choose(n,k) = nCk

Answer (score 40):

If you don't want your code to depend on other packages, you can always just write these functions:

```
perm = function(n, x) {
  factorial(n) / factorial(n-x)
}

comb = function(n, x) {
  factorial(n) / factorial(n-x) / factorial(x)
}
```

Comment: That's a bad idea numerically. R can evaluate `choose(500, 2)` but not `factorial(500)`. You should at least work with `lfactorial` and then take `exp()`. The only reason I'm posting this is that your answer has so many upvotes, it seems people don't know these things...

Answer (score 3):

The `Combinations` package is not part of the standard CRAN set of packages, but is rather part of a different repository, omegahat.  To install it you need to use

```
install.packages("Combinations", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

See the documentation at http://www.omegahat.org/Combinations/

Comment: This also does not work, I think that the R version I'm using is (2.13) is not compatible

Comment: Ah, there was a typo; it should be omegahat, not omeghat.  I copied and pasted the command, but I should have tested it first.  I've updated my answer. This updated code works for me in 2.13.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the package "Combinations" is not updated anymore and does not work with a recent version of R (I was also unable to install it on R 2.13.1 on windows).
The package "combinat" installs without problem for me and might be a solution for you depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions above involve functions designed to list actual combinations, and then apply length function to perform the calculation. This is very inefficient if you just want the number. ncol(combn(1:70,5)) takes about 10 seconds using rstudio.cloud for my system.  choose(70,5) takes less than a second.

As Marius Hofert pointed out there are issues numerically with expressions like factorial(500).

Without using a nonstandard library, I believe choose(n,k) is the best solution for combinations.  The best I know for permutations is choose(n,k)*factorial(k), but please share if anyone knows a direct way to get the permutations.