# How to calculate number of combinations?

Tags: r, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate combination and permutation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906332/how-to-calculate-combination-and-permutation-in-r)

When I try to calculate combinations in R using the `Combinat` package and the `combn` command it gives me all possible combinations. But I just want to return the number of combinations, i.e. I want to get 45 in case of 10C2. What should I do?

Comment: @BlueMagister thanks, never used the package before and did my best to decipher the question.  Post it as an answer I bet it'll be a winner!

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate of another question that was closed as off topic - and that is probably unclear and surely unrelated. It seems that somebody read the title of the question but not the question itself. This question shouldn't be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 42):

Use the base function `choose`:

```
choose(10,2)
#[1] 45
```