# How to calculate permutations of group labels with R?

Tags: r, permutation, permute

Given a vector like:

```
labels <- c(1,2,3,3,3)
```

How to get all possible *group* relabelings? For this example:

```
1,2,3,3,3
1,3,2,2,2
2,1,3,3,3
2,3,1,1,1
3,1,2,2,2
3,2,1,1,1
```

I have been looking at the `permute` package but I don't see how to apply it to this case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906332/how-to-calculate-combination-and-permutation-in-r

Comment: Have you tried `permn` from `combinat`?

Comment: After @khashaa comment I was just reading the combinat doc.

Comment: The `do.call(rbind,permn(labels))` should give more rows than the expected result.

Comment: @akrun yes, I would need only the $n_groups !$ re-labelings corresponding to group labels, not the $n_points!$.

Comment: I edited the question with my (naif?) solution.

Comment: Yup, the **permute** can't do this type of permutation yet. This has come up in some other contexts so I'm looking to add this type of permutation to the package, but I'm crazy busy with the day job for the next couple of months.

Comment: Do not add the solution to your question. Instead you should add an answer.

Comment: There is a one line solution by the package iterpc. http://randy.city/iterpc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this solution

```
labels <- c(1,2,3,3,3)
library(data.table)
a <- do.call(cbind, combinat::permn(unique(labels)))
data.table(a)[,lapply(.SD, function(x)x[labels]),]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1:  1  1  3  3  2  2
#2:  2  3  1  2  3  1
#3:  3  2  2  1  1  3
#4:  3  2  2  1  1  3
#5:  3  2  2  1  1  3
```

Or, just

```
apply(a, 2, function(x) x[labels])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    3    3    2    2
#[2,]    2    3    1    2    3    1
#[3,]    3    2    2    1    1    3
#[4,]    3    2    2    1    1    3
#[5,]    3    2    2    1    1    3
```

Answer (score 0):

I post here my own solution as suggested:

```
library(combinat)

labels <- c(1,2,3,3,3)

group.perms <- permn(unique(labels)) 
for(i in 1:length(group.perms)){
  cat(match(labels, group.perms[[i]]), "\n")
}

#2 1 3 3 3 
#3 1 2 2 2 
#3 2 1 1 1 
#2 3 1 1 1 
#1 3 2 2 2 
#1 2 3 3 3
```

(but I like the second solution proposed by @Khashaa better)