# Converting mathematica formula in PHP

Tags: php, wolfram-mathematica

I have this formula based on mathematica:

```
2*CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2], 30] // N
```

But I have no idea how to convert it in PHP..
This is the original question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619136/calculate-the-probabilities-of-appearing-even-or-odd-numbers-in-a-predefined-set

Can anyone helping me converting the above formula in a working PHP function?
Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you want to change some of those numbers and calculate the result. CDF[BinomialDistribution[a, b], c]==(Beta[1-b, a-Floor[c], 1+Floor[c]] Gamma[1+a])/(Gamma[a-Floor[c]] Gamma[1+Floor[c]]) when 0<=c<=a and it ==1 when a<c and it ==0 otherwise, where Gamma is the usual math gamma function and Beta is described at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Beta.html. That might help you make a little progress.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement it from scratch. Unfortunately I don't know PHP syntax, I write you C code which you can easily traduce yourself:

```
double cdfBinomial(int n ,double p ,int k){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++){
        sum+=combinations(n,i)*pow((double)p,(double)i)*pow((double)(1-p),(double)(n-i));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You have also to implement `combinations` function like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838368/calculating-the-amount-of-combinations).

Comment: Where n,p and k stand for? Sorry I am a little confused :D

Comment: n and p are the parameters of binomial function, while k is your "30", try to look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: I believe you need `i <= k` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo using HAL9000's code in generic *Mathematica* form.

First the CFD version:

```
2*CDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 0.5], 30]
```

> 0.0000785014

And now generic form with the auxiliary `combinations` function:

```
combinations[n0_, k_] := Module[{n = n0},
  If[k > n, 0,
   r = 1; For[d = 1, d <= k, ++d,
    r *= n--;
    r /= d];
   r]]

n = 100; p = 0.5; k = 30;

sum = 0; For[i = 0, i <= k, i++,
 sum += combinations[n, i]*p^i*(1 - p)^(n - i)];

2*sum
```

> 0.0000785014

This page was useful in writing this post: [The Binomial Distribution](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/binom.htm)