# C++ function to calculate factorial returns negative value

Tags: c++, algorithm, factorial, integer-overflow

I've written a C++ function to calculate factorial and used it to calculate **<sup>22</sup>C<sub>11</sub>** (Combination). I have declared a variable `ans` and set it to 0. I tried to calculate

`22C11 = fact(2*n)/(fact(n)*fact(n))`

where i sent `n` as 11. For some reason, i'm getting a negative value stored in answer. How can i fix this?

```
long int fact(long int n) {
    if(n==1||n==0)
        return 1;
    long int x=1;
    if(n>1)
    x=n*fact(n-1);
    return x;
}
```

The following lines are included in the main function:

```
long int ans=0;
    ans=ans+(fact(2*n)/(fact(n)*fact(n)));
cout<<ans;
```

The answer i'm getting is -784
The correct answer should be 705432

**NOTE:** This function is working perfectly fine for n<=10. I have tried long long int instead of long int but it still isn't working.

Comment: Not according to the answer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819189/what-range-of-values-can-integer-types-store-in-c

Comment: As i said, i have already tried `long long int` and `long int` but they weren't working.

Comment: Well, that's the answer, and to get help with code that isnt working you would need to post that code

Comment: `long long int` is typically 64 bits. `22!` is `1124000727777607680000`, which requires at least 70 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unwise to actually calculate factorials - they grow extremely fast. Generally, with combinatorial formulae it's a good idea to look for a way to re-order operations to keep intermediate results somewhat constrained.

For example, let's look at `(2*n)!/(n!*n!)`. It can be rewritten as `((n+1)*(n+2)*...*(2*n)) / (1*2*...*n) == (n+1)/1 * (n+2)/2 * (n+3)/3 ... * (2*n)/n`. By interleaving multiplication and division, the rate of growth of intermediate result is reduced.

So, something like this:

```
int f(int n) {
  int ret = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    ret *= (n + i);
    ret /= i;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TTEZM89998)

Answer (score 2):

22! = 1,124,000,727,777,607,680,000

2<sup>64</sup> = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

So unless you have 128-bit integers for `unsigned long long` you have integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering integer overflow, which causes undefined behaviour.  You could in fact use `long long int`, or `unsigned long long int` to get a little bit more precision, e.g:

```
unsigned long long fact(int n)
{
    if(n < 2)
        return 1;

    return fact(n-1) * n;
}
```

You say you tried this and it didn't work but I'm guessing you forgot to also update the type of `x` or something. (In my version I removed `x` as it is redundant). And/or your calculation still was so big that it overflowed `unsigned long long int`.

You may be interested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838368/calculating-the-amount-of-combinations) which shows an algorithm for working out nCr that doesn't require so much intermediate storage.

Comment: Although recursion with very large numbers generally doesn't lead anywhere good. With factorial, you're going to keep the number small anyways, but every time you call a function from itself, it sets up a new stack frame. You can run out of stack space pretty quickly. For example:
unsigned long long foo(int n){ if (n == 1<<63) return n; else return foo(n+1);

Comment: @Goodies a good point although I would expect compilers to implement *tail recursion optimization* in this case. In fact you can [see that happening here](http://goo.gl/yB6Tj1)

Answer (score 0):

You increasing your chances of success by avoiding the brute force method.

```
COMB(N1, N2) = FACT(N1)/(FACT(N1-N2)*FACT(N2))
```

You can take advantage of the fact that both the nominator and the denominator have a lot of common terms.

```
COMB(N1, N2) = (N1-N2+1)*(N1-N2+2)*...*N1/FACT(N1)
```

Here's an implementation that makes use of that knowledge and computes `COMB(22,11)` with much less risk of integer overflow.

```
unsigned long long comb(int n1, int n2)
{
   unsigned long long res = 1;
   for (int i = (n1-n2)+1; i<= n1; ++i )
   {
      res *= i;
   }

   for (int i = 2; i<= n2; ++i )
   {
      res /= i;
   }

   return res;
}
```