# How I could use tail call optimisation on this combination function?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, combinations, tail-call-optimization

My exercise, that you can see [here](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/estrutura_de_dados/blob/LE1/docs/listas_exercicios/EDI_Atividade_Semana3.org), says that I need to
*implement a recursive version of C(n, k)*.

That's my solution:

```hs
module LE1.Recursao.Combinacao where

combina :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
combina n k | k == 0         = 1
            | n == k         = 1
combina n k | k > 0 && n > k = (combina (n - 1) k) + (combina (n - 1) (k - 1))
combina _ _                  = 0
```

Now I want to create a tail-recursive version of this function, so I don't get stack overflows for large numbers and also calculate the combination quicker!

I'm new to tail call optimisation, but I did that in `Elixir` for the Fibonacci series:

```
defmodule Fibonacci do
  def run(n) when n < 0, do: :error
  def run(n), do: run n, 1, 0
  def run(0, _, result), do: result
  def run(n, next, result), do: run n - 1, next + result, next
end
```

I understand this Fibonacci code and I think that the combination algorithm isn't too different, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: There's no magic quick way to do `C(n, k)` recursively. But you can use the factorial explicit formula to do it mighty quick without recursion. It's also worth noting that [we don't always care about tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042353/does-haskell-have-tail-recursive-optimization) in Haskell as much as we do in other languages.

Comment: Uh... do you actually get a stack overflow with large numbers? I couldn't make that happen in my local tests. For small numbers, the stack is small, and for large numbers it takes so long that I never had the patience to wait for it to get to the part where it would need a big stack, if that were to occur anywhere. Memory usage is completely flat for as long as I care to wait. If you want quicker, you're going to have to use a different algorithm, not merely an optimization of this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Wagner writes

```
combina n k = product [n-k+1 .. n] `div` product [1 .. k]
```

This can get rather inefficient for large `n` and medium-size `k`; the multiplications get huge. How might we keep them smaller? We can write a simple recurrence:

```
combina :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
combina n k
  | k > n || k < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = combina' n k'
  where
    -- C(n,k) and C(n,n-k) are the same,
    -- so we choose the cheaper one.
    k' = min k (n-k)

-- Assumes 0 <= k <= n
combina' _n 0 = 1
combina' n k
  = -- as above
  product [n-k+1 .. n] `div` product [1 .. k]
  = -- expanding a bit
  (n-k+1) * product [n-k+2 .. n] `div` (product [1 .. k-1] * k)
  = -- Rearranging, and temporarily using real division
  ((n-k+1)/k) * (product [n-(k-1)+1 .. n] / product [1 .. k-1]
  = -- Daniel's definition
  ((n-k+1)/k) * combina' n (k-1)
  = -- Rearranging again to go back to integer division
  ((n-k+1) * combina' n (k-1)) `quot` k
```

Putting that all together,

```
combina' _n 0 = 1
combina' n k = ((n-k+1) * combina' n (k-1)) `quot` k
```

Just one problem remains: this definition is not tail recursive. We can fix that by counting up instead of down:

```
combina' n k0 = go 1 1
  where
    go acc k
      | k > k0 = n `seq` acc
      | otherwise = go ((n-k+1)*acc `quot` k) (k + 1)
```

Don't worry about the `` n `seq` `` ; it's of very little consequence.

Note that this implementation uses `O(min(k,n-k))` arithmetic operations. So if `k` and `n-k` are both very large, it will take a long time. I don't know if there's any efficient way to get exact results in that situation; I believe that binomial coefficients of that sort are usually estimated rather than calculated precisely.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional implementation looks like this:

```
combina n k = product [n-k+1 .. n] `div` product [1 .. k]
```

It runs instantly for just about as big a number as you care to put in, and fairly quickly for numbers bigger than you care to put in.

```
> :set +s
> combina 40000 20000
<answer snipped because it's way too big to be useful>
(0.74 secs, 837,904,032 bytes)
```

Meanwhile for your implementation, `combina 30 15` took 7s and `combina 40 20` took longer than I cared to wait -- multiple minutes, at least, even compiled with optimizations rather than interpreted.

It is possible to get still more efficient than this by choosing clever orders of multiplications and divisions, but it's significantly less readable.

Comment: I think I see how implementing the factorial formula could be the answer to the first revision of this question then titled `How I could use tail call optimisation on this combination function?`: Mdsp continues `Now I want to create a [tail-recursive] version`.

Comment: Can you point out (or reference) some of the clever multiplication and division you mention?

Comment: @dfeuer [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838732/791604) describes how to keep the numbers small. The cost of multiplication scales (a little bit) with how big the numbers being multiplied are, so keeping things small should help a little bit.

Comment: I liked this solution although it isn't recursive. However I tested with some inputs and with one from the exercice - `C(49, 6)`, gives me 0...

Comment: @Mdsp, it's important to use `Integer` or `Natural` here, not `Int` or `Word`. The intermediate results can get very large. The link Daniel put in the comments leads to some techniques for avoiding this.

Comment: @dfeuer or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66645347/849891). one more initial multiplication can be avoided, with a test for `n`'s parity.

Comment: @dfeuer my explanation is immediately clear to me though -- the regroup by zipping is self-evident, and divisibility follows after a moment's thought.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Wagner's answer (or my other answer, or similar things) is the right way in practice. But if you want to use the recurrence described in the problem set but want your function to run in a reasonable amount of time, you'll have to structure the solution rather differently. Consider what happens for some `n` and `k` not near a base case.

```
combina n k
  = combina (n - 1) k + combina (n - 1) (k - 1)
  =   combina (n - 2) k       + combina (n - 2) (k - 1)
    + combina (n - 2) (k - 1) + combina (n - 2) (k - 2)
```

See how `combina (n - 2) (k - 1)` is calculated twice here? This process repeats many times, leading to your algorithm taking *exponential* time. Ouch. How can you fix that? Well, imagine making a *table* of all the results of `combina`. Now you can walk along each row of the table to calculate the next one, avoiding the repeated work. This is really just calculating *Pascal's triangle*.

```
combina :: Int -> Int -> Integer
combina n k
  | k > n || k < 0 = 0
  | otherwise = build n !! n !! k

step :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
step xs = 1 : zipWith (+) xs (drop 1 xs) ++ [1]

build :: Int -> [[Integer]]
build n0 = go (n0 + 1) [1]
  where
    go 0 _ = []
    go n row = row : go (n - 1) (step row)
```

The key idea is in `step`, which calculates each row from the previous one.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I didn't understand the `build` part in the combina's second clause... Is it (build(n) !! n) !! k or it's right associative?

Comment: @Mdsp, it's left associative, so `(build n !! n) !! k`. The `k`th element of the `n`th element of `build n`.