# Why was BigInt, BigNum or Arbitrary-precision arithmetic not present in STL or standard libraries for C++?

Tags: c++, biginteger

Is there a specific reason for this?

Was it a design decision?

[Big number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238343/big-number-in-c)  along with other search results show classes written to account for this.

I wonder if the future version would include this feature.

Answer (score 9):

There were at least two big integer proposals to C++11 (n1718, n1744, n2143). All are rejected. Which is why you don't see them in the standard library

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1954.html:

> N1744 Big Integer Library Proposal for C++0x Date: 2005-01-13
>   Status: Closed.
>
> Lillehammer [2005-04]: We haven't seen an analysis of use cases, so we don't know which communities this is important to, what their needs are, and whether this type meets their needs.

Rejection of n1718 and n2143: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2870.html (just a table, no reason given here)